# Appium - Not able to fetch element

Tags: android, selenium, appium

In my native android application, I get a pop-up when firstname is not entered. After clicking on 'OK' button of popup I am not able to switch back to previous layout in selenium.

```
public void submit(){
    System.out.println("--->Before submit"+this.webDriver.getPageSource());  //displays source of layout 1
    System.out.println(this.webDriver.currentActivity());
    this.webDriver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(CreateAccountObjectMap.create_account_submit_button_xpath.getLocator())).click();
}

public void validateNoDataSubmit() throws InterruptedException{
    waitForElement(MobileBy.className(CreateAccountObjectMap.error_box_class.getLocator()));
    System.out.println(this.webDriver.getPageSource());   //Displays new layout2
    WebElement noFirstNameElement = waitForElement(MobileBy.xpath(CreateAccountObjectMap.error_text_xpath.getLocator()));
    waitForElement(MobileBy.xpath(CreateAccountObjectMap.error_box_ok_xpath.getLocator())).click();   //Dismissed error box here
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println("Finished waiting for 10 seconds");
    System.out.println("After clicking"+this.webDriver.getPageSource());  //Script stuck here. If I remove this then unable to find element
}
```

Comment: so,Popup is not closed??or what is happening exactly?what you want?

Comment: Refer to comments in code

Comment: Popup is closed. But after that script is stuck

Comment: Not able to get source of previous layout or fetch elements

Comment: What is exception?

Comment: Like I said, there isn't any. Script is stuck.